# ICollection - Get single value

Tags: c#, .net, icollection

What is the best way to get a value from a ICollection? 
We know the Collection is empty apart from that.

Answer (score 95):

You can use LINQ for this:.

```
var foo = myICollection.OfType<YourType>().FirstOrDefault();
// or use a query
var bar = (from x in myICollection.OfType<YourType>() where x.SomeProperty == someValue select x)
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault is defined on ICollection or IEnumerable (non-generic)? Where?
What would work though: myICollection.OfType<YourType>().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: This is the right answer. First and FirstOrDefault even use that IList optimisation internally where possible.

Comment: I was looking the FirstOrDefault() but intellisense was telling me that no way... until i added the using for System.Linq. So before doing any of this, check you added at the beginning of your code:

`using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 26):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
foreach(object o in collection) {
  return o;
}
```

But this isn't particularly efficient if it's actually a generic collection because IEnumerator implements IDisposable, so the compiler has to put in a try/finally, with a Dispose() call in the finally block.

If it's a non-generic collection, or you know the generic collection implements nothing in its Dispose() method, then the following can be used:

```
IEnumerator en = collection.GetEnumerator();
en.MoveNext();
return en.Current;
```

If you know if may implement IList, you can do this:

```
IList iList = collection as IList;
if (iList != null) {
  // Implements IList, so can use indexer
  return iList[0];
}
// Use the slower way
foreach (object o in collection) {
  return o;
}
```

Likewise, if it's likely it'll be of a certain type of your own definition that has some kind of indexed access, you can use the same technique.

Answer (score 8):

```
collection.ToArray()[i]
```

This way is slow, but very simple to use.

Comment: This copies the entire collection just to get one value.

Comment: "We know the Collection is empty apart from that.". For the sake of simplicity, the above would have its uses. Although not the best generic answer as it would be abused.

Answer (score 5):

Without generics and because `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable` you can do like in example 1. With generics you simple need to do like example 2:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("astring");

ICollection col1 = (ICollection)l;
ICollection<string> col2 = (ICollection<string>)l;

//example 1
IEnumerator e1 = col1.GetEnumerator();
if (e1.MoveNext())
    Console.WriteLine(e1.Current);

//example 2
if (col2.Count != 0)
    Console.WriteLine(col2.Single());
```

Comment: example 2 isn't right because ICollection doesn't implement method Single().

Comment: This is a Linq extension method. Take a look at msdn doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2fx0ty0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you know your collection has only one item, should only ever have one item, you can use the Linq extension method [`Single()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx).

This converts a `ICollection<T>` into a `T` object containing the single item of that collection. If the length of the collection is 0, or more than one, this will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.