# How to Deserialise JSON object and get a value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, icollection

I have this JSON response

```
{
  "multicast_id": 6847210640445644406,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [{
      "message_id": "0:1540898546437583%dadf2158f9fd7ecd"
  }]
}
```

Now how can I get the value of message_id??

I have designed the class this way for de-serialisation

```
public class SingleResponse
{
    public string Multicast_id { get; set; }
    public byte Success { get; set; }
    public byte Failure { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

}

public class Result
{
    public string Message_id { get; set; }
}
```

Is my procedure right?
If yes, how can I get the value of MessageId?

So far I have tried for deserialization and it works fine

```
 SingleResponse singleResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleResponse>(response);
```

and able to get other properties like this way

```
byte success = singleResponse.success
```

Comment: which programming language is this? I'd guess C# but you didn't actually say this or tag it. How are you doing the de-serialisation exactly? Your class structure looks ok, what issue are you facing exactly in obtaining a message ID? What have you tried?

Comment: I am using c# programming language

Comment: Ok. Please edit your question to include _all_ the info I've asked for above. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list of Results and print the message ID from each one, e.g.

```
foreach(Result res in singleResponse.Results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(res.Message_id);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eVg1pQ

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) is some more information about the ICollection interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot
can i do that using for loop? if yes  .. how?

Comment: actually i don't need iterate all item at a time.

Comment: if you just want to fetch a single item you can use Linq, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363326/icollection-get-single-value . You can't  really use a `for` loop meaningfully because you can't access an item in an ICollection by its index directly. But why should you care if it's a `for` or a `foreach`? It's not really important, surely?

Comment: Of course there's also nothing stopping you from using something different in your C# class such as IList or even a concrete class like List (instead of the ICollection)

Comment: linq reference was awesome.can i do that using lamda expression??

Comment: @kamolchandraRoy I'm not quite sure exactly what you have in mind but yes I don't see why not. P.S. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click on the tick next to the answer so it turns green) and/or upvote - thanks.